# Locating Name Manager in Excel for Mac

Tags: ms-office

With named ranges it is more convenient to operate formulas. For instance, instead of typing `=SUM(C20:C30)` you can enter `=SUM(FirstQuarterSales)`

Where is Name Manager located in Excel 2016? I don't see any button in the Formulas Ribbon:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no special button for the Name Manager in any version of Excel for Mac. However, you can call it by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

The dialog window will appear, where you can enter name for a data range and a range of cells:
[image]

Another way is to click Insert>Name>Define and modify,add,or delete data ranges names.

Comment: Just a comment from the experience. Please, be aware that there is probably a bug and Excel may accidentally and randomly change named ranges! Check and if you have same bad experience, just don't use them.